# Not able to add footer item in Recycler View dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am creating a list in which each list item has 3 widgets i.e. 2 EditText and 1 Spinner. And I have one add button to add a new view in the list.

I have created two views one is header view that has all 3 widgets with cross button and footer view that has all 3 widgets with the add button.

Initially, my footer view is shown. When I enter a value on all 3 widgets of that footer view I want to add those values into a model without clicking on it. Now it is working fine when I click on add button but I want to add it without clicking on add button when all values are filled.

Please help.

```java
if (holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
    final FooterViewHolder footerHolder = (FooterViewHolder) holder;

    unitlist = new ArrayList<>();
   // unitlist.add(0, "Select");
    unitlist.add(0, "unit");
    unitlist.add(1, "gram");
    unitlist.add(2, "litre");

    spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.spinner, unitlist) {
        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown);

    ((FooterViewHolder) holder).spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    //spinner select type of life stage

    ((FooterViewHolder) holder).spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            unitName = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            selected_item = ((FooterViewHolder) holder).spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            //Another interface callback
        }
    });


    footerHolder.ibAddMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (footerHolder.etIngredientName.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.pls_enter_ingredient_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (((FooterViewHolder) holder).spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Select")) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.pls_enter_unit_conversion_value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (footerHolder.etAmount.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.pls_enter_qty, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                ArrayList<ModelInventory> modelInventoryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                modelInventoryArrayList = databaseHelper.getInventoryByName(footerHolder.etIngredientName.getText().toString());

                Log.e("TAG", "checkUnit:d "+footerHolder.etAmount.getText().toString() + "))" +modelInventoryArrayList.size());

                if(modelInventoryArrayList.size() >0){

                    for(ModelInventory modelInventory : modelInventoryArrayList){

                        Log.e("TAG", "checkUnit: "+modelInventory.getItemQty() +")))"+unitName );
                        if(modelInventory.getItemQty().equals(unitName)){
                            fragmentNewRecipe.addView(footerHolder.etAmount.getText().toString(), position, footerHolder.etIngredientName.getText().toString(), unitName);

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(activity,R.string.measurement_diff,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    fragmentNewRecipe.addView(footerHolder.etAmount.getText().toString(), position, footerHolder.etIngredientName.getText().toString(), unitName);

                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

View:

[image: View]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding listeners to each edit text and whenever an input change detected, Check whether all inputs are non empty, and add to your list

```
                footerHolder.etAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        if (s.toString() != ""){
                            if (footerHolder.etIngredientName.getText().length() != 0) {
                                //Add item to your list
                            }
                        }

                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
                    });
                footerHolder.etIngredientName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            if (s.toString() != ""){
                                if (footerHolder.etAmount.getText().length() != 0) {
                                    //Add item to your list
                                }
                            }

                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
                        });
```

Comment: I tried this solution earlier but on text change listener it added more list as I am adding tet in edit text

Comment: Yeah, the listener will trigger for every letter you input. What you can do is check entry of a particular character (for eg a space). and in listener do the insertion only when your designated character is entered. so that a new list entry is made only when user terminated the word with a space

Comment: Another method is to check the text length each time and do the list entry code only when a particular length is reached.